# Load file with a relative path

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to load a file in Lisp from a file in the same directory using a relative path.

My file structure looks like this:

```
repo/
    subdir/
        main.lisp
        test.lisp
```

In `main.lisp` I have a number of function definitions, and in `test.lisp` I want to test the functions.

I have tried using `(load "main.lisp")` and `(load "main")` in `test.lisp`, as well as a number of variations on the pathname (i.e., including `./` before the filename) but both times I get the following error (where `<filename>` is the filename passed to the load function):

`File-error in function LISP::INTERNAL-LOAD:  "<filename>" does not exist.`

Is it possible to load `main.lisp` using a relative path?

It may be worth noting that I am running [CMUCL](http://www.cons.org/cmucl/) and executing the code using [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) inside of Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a file is being loaded, the variable `*LOAD-PATHNAME*` is bound to the pathname of the file being loaded, and `*LOAD-TRUENAME*` to its truename.

So, to load a file in the same directory with the file currently being loaded, you can say

```
(load (merge-pathnames "main.lisp" *load-truename*))
```

Comment: Will this only work when contained in a file being loaded? I tried executing this via the REPL, but the value of `*load-truename*` was `nil`. However, it did work when I used `(load "path-to-test.lisp")`.

Comment: Yes, `*load-truename*` is only bound during a `load` operation. Similarly, there are `*compile-file-pathname*` and `*compile-file-truename*` that are only bound during the execution of `compile-file`.

Comment: Sadly this does not work in SLIME, because `*load-truename*` is set to `/tmp`.

Answer (score 5):

jlahd's answer is excellent.

If you need to make different pathname calculations, you can do it with the built-in functions:

```
(let* ((p1    (pathname "test.lisp"))   ; not fully specified
       (name1 (pathname-name p1))       ; the name "test"
       (type1 (pathname-type p1))       ; the type "lisp"
       (p2 #p"/Users/joswig/Documents/bar.text")  ; a complete pathname
       (dir2  (pathname-directory p2))) ; (:ABSOLUTE "Users" "joswig" "Documents")

  ; now let's construct a new pathname

  (make-pathname :name name1
                 :type type1
                 :directory (append dir2 (list "Lisp"))   ; we append a dir
                 :defaults p2))         ; all the defaults
                                        ; relevant when the filesystem supports
                                        ; host, device or version
```

The result: `#P"/Users/joswig/Documents/Lisp/test.lisp"`.

Usually to reuse something like above, one turn it into a utility function...