# Error installing slimv

Tags: vim, scheme, lisp, mit-scheme, slimv

I'm trying to use [slimv](https://bitbucket.org/kovisoft/slimv/downloads?tab=tags), which is recommended in the answer for [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40510933/5399734), under macOS Sierra. However, when I installed this plugin into `~/.vim/plugin`, and ran `vi test.lisp`, I got the following error. The beautiful "Slimv" menu was also not shown.

```
sunqingyaos-MacBook-Air:plugin sunqingyao$ vi ~/.vimrc 
Error detected while processing /Users/sunqingyao/.vim/plugin/ftplugin/clojure/slimv-clojure.vim:
line  196:
E117: Unknown function: SlimvInitBuffer
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Note that currently I don't have Clojure installed on my MacBook Air. All what I want to do is to debug some mit-scheme programs inside vim.

Here is the relevant part of `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:slimv_swank_cmd = '!osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"mit-scheme --load ~/.vim/plugin/slime/start-swank.lisp\""'
```

Version information for vim:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 13 2016 21:22:16)
Included patches: 1-898
Compiled by root@apple.com
```

I'm a vim newbie who don't know much about vim script, so please explain it in detail to me.

Comment: Your version of Slimv seems to be outdated. Grab [the current version](https://bitbucket.org/kovisoft/slimv/downloads?tab=tags) and see if it fixes your problems.

Comment: @romainl Thank you for reminding me for the newest version! Unfortunately however, there still remains an error: `E117: Unknown function: SlimvInitBuffer`. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't install it into `~/.vim/plugin`, you should install it into `~/.vim` because slimv has files in other vim directories outside `plugin` (e.g `ftplugin`, `indent`, `syntax` etc).

Comment: After I move the whole  directory to `~/.vim` and changed the corresponding line in `~/.vimrc` to `let g:slimv_swank_cmd = '!osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"mit-scheme --load ~/.vim/slime/start-swank.lisp\""'`, no errors occur, but nothing happens(i.e. "Slimv" menu still not shown). Here is the output of `:script`: https://gist.github.com/sunqingyao/aa8bc37f0a570ab4355a405bf5909791

Comment: Did you open/create a .lisp, .clj, or .scm file? Slimv is loaded only when one of the compatible file types are edited in vim.

Comment: I've tried opening and creating a `.lisp` file, a `.clj` file, and a `.scm` file, but none of these invoked the menu...

Comment: Here's the `:script` output when I'm editing a `.scm` file: https://gist.github.com/sunqingyao/5bf5d6a34f9794be7f30556ebf896d6a

Comment: From your `:script` output is seems that slimv is loaded (line 25: `~/.vim/ftplugin/slimv.vim`). I don't know what you mean by "...none of these invoked the menu...". The menu isn't automatically invoked. You need to press `,,` (=`<Leader>,`) to invoke the slimv menu. Well, if you use the gui version of vim with the menu constantly displayed then you should see a new menu item appearing in the menu.

Comment: Oh yes, after pressing `,,` I saw something like `:emenu: Slimv.Edit.` appeared at the bottom of my terminal, but I still have some problems using it. According to the [document](http://kovisoft.bitbucket.org/tutorial.html#startup), to use slimv, I have to start a "Swank server" first. How can I start it? I've tried `,c`, but vim told me `SWANK server is not running. Press ENTER to continue.`

Comment: Here is the error output from a newly-created terminal: `;Loading ".vim/slime/start-swank.lisp"...
;Unbound variable: *load-truename*`

Comment: I'm afraid that this goes beyond my competence. As far as I know `*load-truename*` should be bound during the load operation, see e.g. the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800283/load-file-with-a-relative-path) or the [Hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_ld_pns.htm#STload-truenameST).

Comment: Maybe that's specific to Common Lisp? I've tried to use absolute path, but I got another error: `;Unbound variable: :*fasl-directory*`. Seems that all variables are not bound in my mit-scheme implementation.

Comment: Maybe your `g:slimv_swank_cmd` is wrong. I think it should not load `slime/start-swank.lisp` because that's for starting a swank server for lisp. It should load `slime/contrib/swank-mit-scheme.scm` because that's the swank server for MIT-Scheme.

Comment: WOW IT WORKS LIKE MAGIC NOW! Thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128217/discussion-between-sun-qingyao-and-tamas-kovacs).